# What is "JScript Thunk Assembly" assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jscript

For many of my ASP.NET websites I've used reflection to get version information about the loaded assemblies, (I used this for statistics and deployment purposes).

On a few of the websites I've noticed an assembly called `JScript Thunk Assembly`, but I have no idea where it came from - or what it is used for.

I've had a google around for it, but returned nothing useful.

There's no problem with that assembly being there, was more curious of why and where it came from.

---

*Update:* After getting curious about this again, I have found where the "JScript Thunk Assembly" comes from. See this shared-source for .NET 2.0: [`Microsoft.JScript.Runtime.cs#L111`](https://github.com/gbarnett/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/d63349c09c2e93e4bfc4c8b147ff0805f36cec68/jscript/engine/runtime.cs#L111).

I can see that a call to `CreateThunkModuleBuilder()` is made from the internal `ThunkModuleBuilder` property, but I am unsure how or why it is call from my own application.
*(The mystery continues...)*

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it extended the question with further research. I would still like to know what triggers the generation of the `JScript Thunk Assembly`.